# 12.04: Language indicator problem

Tags: 12.04, indicator

My language indicator doesn't show the current language. It changes the language with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, but it doesn't show the current language.

How can I fix it? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with GNOME shell, and also I am new in Ubuntu.

see my screenshot [here](http://pasteboard.co/AEi2P94.png)

Comment: @K7AAY thank you for mentioned that, but actually as you can see I asked this question 4 years and 7 months ago, anyway thank you !

Comment: My apologies; corrected.

Comment: @K7AAY your welcome, I'm really glad that you are trying to improve this community. Thank you.